# pandasで日付の最小値、最大値を自動抽出するには

Tags: python, python3, pandas

下記表のような時系列温度データにつき、`2000年、2001年・・・`と、各年ごとの値の平均値を計算しています。

日付のstart-endが分かっている場合、

```
df['2000-01-04':'2000-12-27'].mean()
df['2001-01-05':'2001-12-28'].mean()
```

などと値を直指定すればいいと思うのですが、データを見ていちいち確認するのではなく、プログラム的にstart/endを判定したい場合、どのようにプログラムを組んだらいいのでしょうか？

`df.min()`を使えばとも思ったのですが、各年ではなくデータ全体の最小値を抽出してしまいます。

```
date(index) 気温
2000-01-04 -1℃
2000-01-05 0℃
・
・
2000-12-27 8℃
2001-01-05 2℃
2001-01-06 3℃
・
・
2001-12-28 -1℃
```

Comment: start, end を求めるのではなく、`groupby()` を使ってみてはどうでしょう。`df.groupby(df.index.year).mean()`

Answer (score 1):

```
df.resample('1Y').mean()
```

では？

```
pd.Series(df.index).min()
pd.Series(df.index).max()
df.index[0]
df.index[-1]
df.idxmin()
df.idxmax()
```

indexの最大と最小は用途によって使い分ければいいかと